# Get additional information from an edge after a graph search using Djikstra algorithm

Tags: java, path-finding

I'm using [this implementation](http://en.literateprograms.org/index.php?title=Special%3ADownloadCode/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm_%28Java%29&oldid=15444) to perform a graph search. The search is working. The shortest path is returned by this function:

```
public static List<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Vertex target)
{
    List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();

    for (Vertex vertex = target; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.previous)
        path.add(vertex);

    Collections.reverse(path);
    return path;
}
```

However, I added a few properties to the edges, and I need that information extracted to.

How do I find out which edge has been used for the path?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure, your graph doesn't contain multiple edges with the same source and targetnode, you can reconstruct the edges from the adjacencies and previous field of class Vertex.

Something like the following should collect all edges in a List (not tested).

```
List<Edge> edge_path = new ArrayList<Edge>();
for (int i = 1; i < path.size(); i++) {
    Vertex v = path.get(i);

    for (Edge e: v.previous.adjacencies)
        if (e.target == v) {
            edge_path.add(e);
            break;
        }
```

However if your graph contains multi edges, you have to adapt the path finding algorithm itself.

Comment: What if the graph has multiple edges. Is there an alternative to Djikstra (eg A*)?

Comment: The edge of the first vertex is null. How to handle this situation?

Comment: Even if the graph has multiple edges, you can use Djikstra. You can easily adjust the code such that not only the nearest predecessor (Vertex.previous) is stored but also which edge you used to reach that node. Just add a new field of type Edge to class Vertex and assign the appropriate edge in Dijkstra.computePaths() whenever there is an assignment to previous.

Comment: What do you mean by "The edge of the first vertex"? If your path has n nodes, there are only (n-1) edges. In case of the implementation of Dijkstra used here, every Vertex stores it's predecessor (Vertex.previous). Which in case of the start node (path.get(0)) is of course null. That's the reason why the above loop starts at 1.